# pgf-blur not working AtEndDocument

Tags: tikz-pgf, shadows

With the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\AtEndDocument{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black,   
blur shadow={shadow blur radius=1.5ex}]
(0,0) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black,
blur shadow={shadow blur radius=1.5ex}]
(0,0) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the right blurred shadow in the first `tikzpicture` environment, but a solid black background frame (not even a shadow properly) in the last one, within the `\AtEndDocument` hook. Why is it so and how can the blurred shadow be obtained also in the latter case?

The picture code has been copied from the `pgf-blur` documentation.

Comment: `AtEndDocument` is not the last page, you don't mean that right?

Comment: @percusse: My original aim was to use this in a class file in order to have a picture as the last thing to be typeset, and to do so automatically; i.e., without any "manual" intervention  by the document's author. In particular, after everything typeset within the `document` environment.

Comment: I get the same picture (TikZ/PGF 3.0)

Comment: @egreg: After switching to v3.0.0 it works. Could you possibly turn your comment into an answer? Btw, I couldn't get it yet from a CTAN repository.

Comment: @Marcos I made the update yesterday on TeX Live; it's possible that your repository is a bit behind schedule. It seems that MiKTeX is still at 2.10, though. So it's just a question of waiting a few days.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I'm on MikTeX. Nonetheless, I installed v3.0 from another repository.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an outdated version of a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I get with TikZ/PGF version 3.0; an update on your side seems the best thing to do.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\textheight}{5cm} % just for the example

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\AtEndDocument{\par\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black,
blur shadow={shadow blur radius=1.5ex}]
(0,0) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black,
blur shadow={shadow blur radius=1.5ex}]
(0,0) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]